# Undeclared identifie trying to make a reflection token

Tags: reflection, token, ethereum, solidity

I'm gettin "undeclared identifier" in this line:

```
// set the rest of the contract variables
    wannaSwapRouterV2 = _wannaSwapRouterV2;
```

Not sure exactly what I need to change. Full code:

```
contract TOKEN is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
using SafeMath for uint256;
using Address for address;

mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;

mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
address[] private _excluded;

uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
uint256 private _tTotal = 1000000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
uint256 private _tFeeTotal;

string private _name = "TOKEN";
string private _symbol = "TOKEN";
uint8 private _decimals = 9;

uint256 public _taxFee = 5;
uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;

uint256 public _liquidityFee = 5;
uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

IWannaSwapRouterV2 public immutable wannaswapV2Router;
address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;

bool inSwapAndLiquify;
bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;

uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 5000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
uint256 private numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = 500000 * 10**6 * 10**9;

event MinTokensBeforeSwapUpdated(uint256 minTokensBeforeSwap);
event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
event SwapAndLiquify(
    uint256 tokensSwapped,
    uint256 ethReceived,
    uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
);

modifier lockTheSwap {
    inSwapAndLiquify = true;
    _;
    inSwapAndLiquify = false;
}

constructor () public {
    _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
    
    IWannaSwapRouterV2 _wannaSwapRouterV2 = IWannaSwapRouterV2(0xa3a1eF5Ae6561572023363862e238aFA84C72ef5);
     // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
    IWannaSwapPair = IWannaSwapFactory(_wannaSwapRouterV2.factory())
        .createPair(address(this), _wannaSwapRouterV2.WETH());

    // set the rest of the contract variables
    wannaSwapRouterV2 = _wannaSwapRouterV2;
    
    //exclude owner and this contract from fee
    _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
    _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
    
    emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
}

function name() public view returns (string memory) {
    return _name;
}

function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
    return _symbol;
}

function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
    return _decimals;
}

function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
    return _tTotal;
}

function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
    if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
    return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
}

function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
    _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
    return _allowances[owner][spender];
}

function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
    _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
    return true;
}

function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
    return true;
}

function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
    return true;
}

function isExcludedFromReward(address account) public view returns (bool) {
    return _isExcluded[account];
}

function totalFees() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _tFeeTotal;
}

function deliver(uint256 tAmount) public {
    address sender = _msgSender();
    require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
    (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
    _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
    _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
    _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
}

function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
    require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
    if (!deductTransferFee) {
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        return rAmount;
    } else {
        (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        return rTransferAmount;
    }
}

function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
    require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
    uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
    return rAmount.div(currentRate);
}

function excludeFromReward(address account) public onlyOwner() {
    // require(account != 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D, 'We can not exclude Uniswap router.');
    require(!_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
    if(_rOwned[account] > 0) {
        _tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }
    _isExcluded[account] = true;
    _excluded.push(account);
}

function includeInReward(address account) external onlyOwner() {
    require(_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
        if (_excluded[i] == account) {
            _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
            _tOwned[account] = 0;
            _isExcluded[account] = false;
            _excluded.pop();
            break;
        }
    }
}
    function _transferBothExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
    _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
    _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
    _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
    _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);        
    _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
    _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
}

    function excludeFromFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
    _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
}

function includeInFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
    _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
}

function setTaxFeePercent(uint256 taxFee) external onlyOwner() {
    _taxFee = taxFee;
}

function setLiquidityFeePercent(uint256 liquidityFee) external onlyOwner() {
    _liquidityFee = liquidityFee;
}

function setMaxTxPercent(uint256 maxTxPercent) external onlyOwner() {
    _maxTxAmount = _tTotal.mul(maxTxPercent).div(
        10**2
    );
}

function setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
    swapAndLiquifyEnabled = _enabled;
    emit SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
}

 //to recieve ETH from uniswapV2Router when swaping
receive() external payable {}

function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
    _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
    _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
}

function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getTValues(tAmount);
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, _getRate());
    return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
}

function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
    uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
    return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
}

function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
    uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity);
    return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
}

function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
    (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
    return rSupply.div(tSupply);
}

function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
    uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
    uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
        if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
    }
    if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
    return (rSupply, tSupply);
}

function _takeLiquidity(uint256 tLiquidity) private {
    uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
    uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
    _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rLiquidity);
    if(_isExcluded[address(this)])
        _tOwned[address(this)] = _tOwned[address(this)].add(tLiquidity);
}

function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
    return _amount.mul(_taxFee).div(
        10**2
    );
}

function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
    return _amount.mul(_liquidityFee).div(
        10**2
    );
}

function removeAllFee() private {
    if(_taxFee == 0 && _liquidityFee == 0) return;
    
    _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
    _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
    
    _taxFee = 0;
    _liquidityFee = 0;
}

function restoreAllFee() private {
    _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
    _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;
}

function isExcludedFromFee(address account) public view returns(bool) {
    return _isExcludedFromFee[account];
}

function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
    require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

    _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
    emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
}

function _transfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
) private {
    require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
    require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
    if(from != owner() && to != owner())
        require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");

    // is the token balance of this contract address over the min number of
    // tokens that we need to initiate a swap + liquidity lock?
    // also, don't get caught in a circular liquidity event.
    // also, don't swap & liquify if sender is uniswap pair.
    uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
    
    if(contractTokenBalance >= _maxTxAmount)
    {
        contractTokenBalance = _maxTxAmount;
    }
    
    bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
    if (
        overMinTokenBalance &&
        !inSwapAndLiquify &&
        from != uniswapV2Pair &&
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled
    ) {
        contractTokenBalance = numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
        //add liquidity
        swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
    }
    
    //indicates if fee should be deducted from transfer
    bool takeFee = true;
    
    //if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
    if(_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]){
        takeFee = false;
    }
    
    //transfer amount, it will take tax, burn, liquidity fee
    _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount,takeFee);
}

function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
    // split the contract balance into halves
    uint256 half = contractTokenBalance.div(2);
    uint256 otherHalf = contractTokenBalance.sub(half);

    // capture the contract's current ETH balance.
    // this is so that we can capture exactly the amount of ETH that the
    // swap creates, and not make the liquidity event include any ETH that
    // has been manually sent to the contract
    uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

    // swap tokens for ETH
    swapTokensForEth(half); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered

    // how much ETH did we just swap into?
    uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

    // add liquidity to uniswap
    addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
    
    emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
}

function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
    // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = wannaswapV2Router.WETH();

    _approve(address(this), address(wannaswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

    // make the swap
    wannaswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenAmount,
        0, // accept any amount of ETH
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
    );
}

function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
    // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
    _approve(address(this), address(wannaswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

    // add the liquidity
    wannaswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
        address(this),
        tokenAmount,
        0, // slippage is unavoidable
        0, // slippage is unavoidable
        owner(),
        block.timestamp
    );
}

//this method is responsible for taking all fee, if takeFee is true
function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount,bool takeFee) private {
    if(!takeFee)
        removeAllFee();
    
    if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
    } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
    } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
    } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
    } else {
        _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
    
    if(!takeFee)
        restoreAllFee();
}

function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
    _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
    _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
    _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
    _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
}

function _transferToExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
    _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
    _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
    _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);           
    _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
    _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
}

function _transferFromExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
    _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
    _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
    _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);   
    _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
    _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in that line.
You declared `IWannaSwapRouterV2 public immutable wannaswapV2Router;`
Then you want to assign _wannaSwapRouterV2 to `wannaSwapRouterV2`

Comment: The typo is the capital S? Or should it be _wannaSwapRouterV2 = wannaSwapRouterV2?

Comment: not sure how to do it

Comment: You declared your immutable state variable above as `IWannaSwapRouterV2 public immutable wannaswapV2Router;`
if you want to assign it a value, you also need to use `wannaswapV2Router` like `wannaswapV2Router = _wannaSwapRouterV2` or you need to declare `wannaSwapRouterV2` as a state variable as well, because as I can see up to that point it just doesn't exist

Comment: unfortunately I have no clue on where and how I do this. thanks regardless